routing issue in next-intl (next.js)
I am building a website in NEXT.js with translations using the package next-intl. I DO NOT want to have a /en or / fr tag at the end of my website link, and that can be avoided by using
localePrefix: 'never'  in my middleware.js file. Now the website works on the homepage (i.e., I can switch languages), but when switching to another page, it shows ERROR: PAGE NOT FOUND.
Switching pages on my website uses the below function
export function goToEvent(eventId,eventName,locale) {
  return `${locale}/event/index/${eventId}/${eventName
    .replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "")
    .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
    .replace(/-+$/, "")}`;
}

When I remove localePrefix: 'never' from the middleware it works. I need a workaround where I can switch pages without including /locale in my website link.
